# Play a sound or chime through ssh

Tags: matlab, ssh, audio

I've a nice question for you all. I'm performing some numerical analysis though SSH connection with my Linux machine. Since each numerical analysis lasts for 3-4 minutes during them I'm doing some other stuff for my work and most of the times I keep forgetting to check my terminal and run a new analysis.
Do you know how to play a sound or something else that helps me remebering to check my terminal and do a new run?
I'm working on OS X and my remote machine is a Ubuntu Linux running MATLAB.

edit:
To clarify the situation: I have a OS X machine which I use to connect remotely to a Ubuntu linux desktop via SSH. I'm using matlab runtime on the SSH remote machine. I just want to receive a chime at the end of every matlab simulation on my local machine, not the remote one. That's all.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Play a reminder sound after something is done on the remote machine?

Comment: So you want to play on the machine running matlab? Then you could try this snippet in matlab: `load handel; sound(y,Fs)` The other way I actually send myself a tweet or email as reminder - which will then also produce a sound ;)

Comment: @EitanT just need a ping or bell (OS X default is 'dong') sound to remind me that the command is finished, but in the matlab shell..

Comment: @bdecaf I'm sending myself an email for long run analyses, such as 10-30hs but in this way I'll receive 1000 mails in a day! :)

Comment: @Nicholas So you're running MATLAB on a remote machine, and you want to play a sound a on the local machine when MATLAB finishes its work?

Comment: @EitanT exactly my friend

Comment: Oh that reminds me on the say command of macs - https://gohgarry.wordpress.com/2010/01/16/fun-with-mac-say-command/ - you could issue one of these. Might freak your coworkers ;)

Comment: @bdecaf I knew that but it works only on my local machine, my problem is that I'm connected to a remote machine though SSH

Comment: @EitanT reading though that 3d, it seems that they are trying to do the opposite, playing a local mp3 to remote machine. I don't wanna play any mp3, just a system sound as Magnus suggested below, but after every matlab command, I can't find the right bash script to use :(

Comment: @Nicholas It's the same thing. The issuer of the "play" command is the MATLAB machine, and it should do so whenever its work is done. The "play" command itself is outside the scope of StackOverflow, but you can find it using [basic Googling](http://goo.gl/q9oiW)...

Comment: so now I'm confused - we had sound output on the "remote machine" and sound output on the "local mac" - and none is useful. Can you clarify your setup?

Comment: @bdecaf I'm confused too because I cannot solve the problem, even though I've used and I'm using Google always before posting...

Answer (score 5):

On most Terminals and shells, this will produce an audible *ping* or *bell*:

```
echo -e '\a'
```

EDIT: you could also use this as a timer, like so:

```
(sleep 60; echo -e '\a') &
```

this will wait for 60 seconds and then produce aforementioned *ping*

Comment: So what OP should do is to replace the `sleep 60` with the ssh command on the calling machine. When the command finishes, the beep will be played. Just to clear that up :-)

Comment: That's a very interesting trick I didn't know that. It's very nice. However my problem is that I'm working on MATLAB environment while I use SSH. I mean, I use SSH remote connection and than use the matlab propmpt to lauch commands. I'll try it anyway to do that using > command, I'll let you know

Comment: Ah, heh, I thought you had an actual SSH shell open with a good ol' bash or something. Well, if it puts text on the console, you could try to produce the bell character in your matlab script when it's done... can't tell you how to do that in matlab though :).

Answer (score 0):

Use the matlab command to make a chime:

```
  beep
```

Comment: You might also have to enable sounds on your ssh link.

Comment: Mar How can I enable that? Is it automatic (default)?